# How to access video in Surface view

Tags: android, video, surfaceview

I am doing multimedia application. I have tried several different examples to implement videos in surface view but I cannot get. i can hear the sound but no visual is appearing. is there any possibilities to get a video in surface view.  My target SDK is 2.2 API level 8. Even I installed my apk to mobile device, still nothing will changed. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to play your video, stream it or copy it to your sdcard or in the /res folder but I've got the following to play video. I can choose whether to stream it or play from a folder on my sdcard

Video.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Movie extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);
        VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.movie);

        //this is the place where you define where to get the video from (this can be from your sd or a stream)
        video.setVideoPath(
        "/sdcard/video/videofile.mp4"

        /*"rtsp://Youtube Stream*/
                );

        //after the video is loaded it will then start
        video.start();
    }
}
```

video_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/movie"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </VideoView>    
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope this will help you!
I also had several problems with SurfaceView but this way my problems were solved.

Comment: If this answer was helpful please mark is as answered. Otherwise we can find another solution?